# Meta-analysis in metafor: using replicates instead of variance in rma.mv

Tags: r, meta-analysis

How can I perform a multilevel meta-analysis without sampling variance? Is it possible to weight the observations by the number of replicates in this way:

```
dat$we<-1/(dat$Replicates)
res <- rma.mv(yi, we, random =~1|Experiment/ID, data=dat)
```

or are you supposed to use the "weight" argument in rma.mv instead?

I am conducting a meta-analysis on response ratios. The idea is to calculate sampling variance using the the forumla provided by escalc() function based on Hedges et al. (1999). However, less than 50% of studies found report values for standard deviation, while all studies report at least the number of replicates. So I am looking for a way to perform a weighted meta-analysis including studies that reported no sampling variance (and eventually make a comparison with a limited dataset including weightable studies).

Comment: Sampling vsriance  = S.D. ?

Comment: Your interest is  in the very beginning of question body or you need an answer to what you say at the end part of your question body ?

Comment: An edit of question may help one of reputed users of site to answer your querry more correctly.

Comment: There is a lot that is not clear in your question. Here are some additional things that need to be addressed to get a useful answer. What is the nature of your effect size (yi in your code)? Is it a standardized mean difference or something else? Is what is being measured across studies identical (i.e., the same response variable in the same metric)? Ultimately, you need to know the variance of the effect size (i.e., its squared standard error). Depending on the answers to the above, you may or may not need the SD for the response variable from each study to determine this.

Comment: It doesn't look that tricky the question to me: can you use the code above to weight a meta-analysis by the number of replicates of each studies or should you use the "weight" argument? yi is a logtransformed response ratio.

Comment: If all you want to know is whether you need to use the weight argument for valid results, then the answer is yes. These analyses are inverse variance weighted (the variance is the squared standard error) and will not produce accurate results with other weights. However, your question raises other issues. If you also want advice on how to deal with all the missing standard deviations, then answering the questions in the comments above is critical.

Comment: Thanks dbwilson. Probably I should have asked this differently then: can you fit a multilevel model via rma.mv() leaving out the 'variance' argument and weight the meta-analysis usign only the number of replicates?